# split double quoted string into array in javascript

Tags: javascript

say I have a long string containing
"abc""xyz""123"
I'd like to split it into
["abc", "xyz", "123"]
how? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the precise definition of Javascript's string.split?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56263194/what-is-the-precise-definition-of-javascripts-string-split)

Comment: Quick and dirty `'"abc""xyz""123"'.split('"').filter(Boolean)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways to do it

Quick and dirty with split and filter out the empties

```js
var string = '"abc""xyz""123"'
var result = string.split('"').filter(Boolean);
console.log(result);
```

Splitting with slice

```js
var string = '"abc""xyz""123"'
var result = string.slice(1, string.length -1).split('""');
console.log(result);
```

---

A regular expression

```js
var string = '"abc""xyz""123"'
var result = string.match(/[^"]+/g)
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const input = '"abc""xyz""123"';

input.replace(/^"|"$/g, "").split('""'); // ["abc","xyz","123"]
```